# Sum time duration by location change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing MySQL query (I am a newbie so please be gentle) that I need to modify but am struggling to determine the changes required -

```
SELECT assetid, locationid, ts,    
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,    
    (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM logs WHERE ts< t.ts),
    ts
  ) secdiff
FROM logs t    
where assetid = 1157    
order by ts DESC
```

which returns (correctly)

```
id   location    datetime       time difference (between rows)    
1157    1   2015-07-02 10:21:56 2    
1157    1   2015-07-02 10:21:54 2    
1157    2   2015-07-02 10:21:52 2    
1157    2   2015-07-02 10:21:50 2    
1157    2   2015-07-02 10:21:48 2    
1157    1   2015-07-02 10:21:46 2    
1157    1   2015-07-02 10:21:44 6    
1157    1   2015-07-02 10:21:38 2
```

I need to be able to determine the total duration spent at each location (location can be other numbers besides 1 & 2) but not grouped by location, rather separated by / until each location change. The time between rows will vary (not always 2 seconds). The assetid will change depending on the main query.

So the result would be (for assetid 1157):

```
id        location  duration
1157        1         4
1157        2         6
1157        1         8
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last sum of duration by 10? Please be correct in your sample data, or it will be confusing.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your table called `logs`.

Comment: Your query calculates time difference for **July, 02 2015 10:21:38** as **NULL** - which would be in line with the last duration given as **8**.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the trick:

```
SET @locationID=0,@ts=NULL,@changed=0;

SELECT
  MIN(assetID) AS id
  , MIN(locationID) AS location
  , SUM(secDiff) AS duration
FROM
  (SELECT
    assetID
    , locationID
    , @changed := IF(locationID <> previousLocationID, @changed + 1, @changed) AS changed
    , IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                           previousTs,
                           ts
                           ),
             0
      ) AS secDiff
  FROM
    (SELECT
      assetID
      , locationID
      , @locationID AS previousLocationID
      , @locationID := locationID AS currentLocationID
      , ts
      , @ts AS previousTs
      , @ts := ts AS currentTs
    FROM Logs L1
    WHERE assetid = 1157    
    ORDER BY ts
    ) L2
  ORDER BY ts
  ) L3
GROUP BY changed
ORDER BY changed DESC
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b059e/1).

**Update:**

If you need to join additional tables, you should actually `JOIN` and not sub-select. As there is a `GROUP BY` at the currently outmost level, the existing statement needs to be wrapped in another set of parentheses - to prevent grouping over the fact tables. With some other adjustments towards that end:

```
SET @locationID=0,@ts=NULL,@changed=0;

SELECT
  A.name
  , L4.assetID
  , L.name
  , L4.locationID
  , duration
FROM
  (SELECT
    MIN(assetID) AS assetID
    , MIN(locationID) AS locationID
    , SUM(secDiff) AS duration
    , changed
  FROM
    (
-- no change in here
    ) L3
  GROUP BY changed
  ) L4
JOIN Asset A
  ON L4.assetID = A.id
JOIN Location L
  ON L4.locationID = L.id
ORDER BY changed DESC
;
```

Expanded [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e4a8/1).

**Update 2:**

The most straightforward way to address duplicate listings should be to `DISTINCT` them away as the very first step:

```
-- no change here
  (SELECT
    assetID
    , locationID
    , @locationID AS previousLocationID
    , @locationID := locationID AS currentLocationID
    , ts
    , @ts AS previousTs
    , @ts := ts AS currentTs
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
      assetID
      , locationID
      , ts
    FROM Logs
    WHERE assetid = 1157
    ) L1
  ORDER BY ts
  ) L2
-- no change here either
```

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb47/1) returns for the duplicated **Logs** data the same result set as [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c9a4/1), where the earlier query runs against data with no duplicates.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Abecee. If I wanted to 'join' to two other tables (assetid is associated with a 'name' in a table named asset, and a 'location name' in a table named location) would I have to add another sub select. i tried this before but it significantly slowed the query (which then took minutes to process 1000 rows).  Thanks. Active

Comment: No: You should actually go for a proper `JOIN`. Just wrap the above statement without the very last `ORDER BY` into another set of parentheses, pull **changed** up to this level (for the final sorting), join the two fact tables, sort by change. Please, see update above.

Comment: Thanks again Abecee. Though I am getting the message Unknown column 'L4.assetID' in 'field list' Regards Active

Comment: Apologies, a typo on my part. Unfortunately though one of the additional statements has resulted in aggregation, there are now only 3 rows being output. Regards. Active.

Comment: There are only three in the expected output. ?? Please demonstrate using a Fiddle.

Comment: Apologies, I did not make my comment clear. In your original query (seems to do the trick) the result was around 100 rows (which is correct). When the update is added (with the joins etc) the result was only 3 rows (I was expecting the 100 rows with each row showing the asset's name and location's name). Something in the added sql causes an aggregation to occur.

Comment: Tried to show that there are many more rows in the logs table but Fiddle wont let me build the schema.                                               (1157, 1, '2015-07-02 10:21:56'),
(1157, 1, '2015-07-02 10:21:54'),
  (1157, 2, '2015-07-02 10:21:52'),
  (1157, 2, '2015-07-02 10:21:50'),
  (1157, 2, '2015-07-02 10:21:48'),
  (1157, 1, '2015-07-02 10:21:46'),
  (1157, 1, '2015-07-02 10:21:44'),
  (1157, 1, '2015-07-02 10:21:38'),
  (1157, 2, '2015-07-02 10:21:20'),
  (1157, 2, '2015-07-02 10:21:10'),
; also the locationID can be other numbers besides 1 & 2.  Thanks

Comment: Seems to be working now ? Only nice to have would be that occasionaly the duration column shows 0  (this is due to multiple datetimes of the same datetime in the original table), adding a CASE or something to prevent those displaying would be beneficial. Thanks again.

Comment: The only reason coming to my mind right away for the updated query showing less records is, the `JOIN` conditions not to be met. I added the two additional records from your comment, duplicated the whole block, changed the time for the copy to one minute earlier, changed some **locationID**s to **3**, added a record in **Location**. Looks OK to me: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb47/1). Duplicate datetimes I'd `DISTINCT` away. See update.

Comment: I eventually added 'where duration != 0' as the last but one line and that removed the zero time rows (then resulted in some duplicate locations being in consecutive rows but that is not critical). Thanks again for your help Abecee (and thanks to this forum). Regards Active.

Comment: Abecee, if you are still around, is it possible to rewrite the sub-queries as joins? You may see in my other post (and on some forums) that sub-queries do not work properly when sql is run in java / jsp, I have tried this and there is no resulting output.

Comment: Commented [Convert sub queries to joins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480084/convert-sub-queries-to-joins)...